# Is a render farm suitable for using high-res stills?

Tags: rendering

This question is primarily for curiosity. I'm aware that render farms are used as a method to speed up rendering time for animation sequences. Is it a good alternative to use for high-res stills that would take a lot more time to render by just using a standard computer to do so?
If there is such an option, where can it be found?

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the render farm you plan to use. Normally a render will generate a complete image which means animations can easily take advantage of multiple computers as each computer can render a single frame from the animation.

It is possible to cut up a single render into multiple pieces that can later be stitched together into a larger image, this will allow multiple computers to work on the same larger final image. Blender's [render border](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/types/camera/introduction.html#render-border) option can be used with a python script like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38223109/2684771), it is possible to use imagemagick to [automatically stitch](https://superuser.com/a/290679) the pieces into one image.

Some commercial render farms include an option to do this, [Render.st](https://render.st) is one example. If you are creating a personal render farm then chances are you will need to add this ability yourself.